# Dataframe if a condition is met on a dataframe column then get this row and the next 3 rows in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to write a code so that if a condition is met on a dataframe column then I can get this row and the next 3 rows in a dataframe?

Each time my funding rate is greater than 0.0363 I want that row and the next 3 rows of the matched row.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) from the built-in module [`functools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html) to do it dynamically:

```
import functools

N = 3
cond = df['Funding Rate'].str.strip('%').astype(float).gt(0.0363)
df[functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x | y, [cond.shift(i) for i in range(N + 1)])]
```

Comment: I have updated the question.
Can you check it again?

Comment: Updated. Check my answer now :)

Comment: Also, it might be a good idea to go through some of [your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17587311/zeshan-ahmed-nobin?tab=questions) and accept answers that helped you. When people look at your profile and see that you've not accepted any answers to your questions yet, they may very well avoid answering your future questions.